# How can I use my C program's binary file after as a filter?

Tags: bash, shell

I have written a program that reads in input from a file or stdin, sorts in and writes it to an output file or stdout. I want to be able to use the binary like all of the filter-like programs (grep, tr, sed).

For example: I want to be able to type in something like, "cat myfile.txt | myfilter --action sort > myoutputfile" instead of cat myfile.txt | ./myfilter --action sort > myoutputfile.

Comment: Klutt is correct. In addition you could put . (Dot) in your path string if you don’t want to have to type ./ in front of executables in the current directory. The hazard is that you may end up executing local files unintentionally.

Comment: Copy it to /usr/bin

Comment: @MikeWodarczyk You could add dot to the path, but I really want to stress that it is NOT recommended.

Comment: Please mark the answer you think is best as accepted. (I would recommend Justice's answer)

Comment: Thanks Klutt, Justice and others. After following the steps, I tried "myfilter --input myfile.txt --output myoutputfile --action sort ", I get the following output: "-bash: myfilter: command not found". Need help fixing this. 1) mkdir ~/bin folder. 2) In .bashrc. added the following line at the end, 'export PATH="/home/$USER/bin:$PATH"' Do I have to modify $USER and $PATH to say 'root' and path of myfilter binary file? 3) Created a symlink using "ln -sf ~/path/to/filter ~/bin/filter". 4) refreshed current terminal session using "source ~/.bashrc".

Comment: The root user is special and does not have it's home directory in `/home/$USER`, but directly in `/$USER`, which in this case of course is `/root`. So if you want to do this for the root user you need to use that directory instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*From the sound of it, you're on a linux machine, so I will use that for my answer*

First, you will want make a new folder:

`$ mkdir ~/bin`

After that, you will need to add the new folder to your `path`:

```
$ nano ~/.bashrc
# Add the following to the end of your ~/.bashrc file while using nano
# or your text editor of choice:
export PATH="/home/$USER/bin:$PATH"
```

The next part can differ depending on how you want to do it. Since its your own personal binary, it might just be easier to add the binary into the folder. Otherwise, you could create a symlink to the file.

*To create a symlink:*

```
$ ln -sf ~/path/to/filter ~/bin/filter
```

*To move the file into the bin folder*

```
$ mv ~/path/to/filter ~/bin
```

Finally, after you've chosen the method (and the executable is somehow accessible from the `~/bin/` folder, run the following command:

***Please note, `source` is only to refresh your current terminal session, you should not have to do this again***

`$ source ~/.bashrc`

Comment: It could be worth mentioning that you don't need to run `source` everytime. It's just needed for the current session.

Comment: Naming the folder `.bin` makes it hidden; there is no obvious reason to do that.

Comment: @rici you are right, I prefer my executable folder hidden as there's no real need to see it

Comment: To each their own, and you are certainly entitled to that preference. On the other hand, having ~/bin (and some other TLAs) lets you build and install personal copies of software with `./configure --prefix=$HOME && make && make install`, which I find handy. Anyway, I think it's worth mentioning that this is a choice, and there is no standard or even best practice document (afaik) which suggests using hidden files.

Comment: @rici I did add a note into the answer. Is there a best practice for keeping it not hidden? If so, I will modify my answer with the proper format

Comment: Not that I know of, but it is pretty standard. For example, debian/ubuntu shell startup scripts automatically add `$HOME/bin` to `$PATH` if the directory exists, so all you need to do to get your executables to work is to create the `~/bin` directory and put the executables into it (and restart your shell sessions, of course). Which means that the `./configure --prefix=$HOME` line I mentioned earlier is the expected way to compile and install an application into your home directory.

Comment: @rici thank you, I have updated accordingly. Its better anyway, as I feel like visual learners might have trouble if they've created the file, but cannot see it in the explorer or `ls` command.

Comment: Thanks Klutt, Justice and others. After following the steps, I tried "myfilter --input myfile.txt --output myoutputfile --action sort ", I get the following output: "-bash: myfilter: command not found". Need help fixing this. 
1) mkdir ~/bin folder.
2) In .bashrc. added the following line at the end, 'export PATH="/home/$USER/bin:$PATH"' Do I have to modify $USER and $PATH to say 'root' and path of myfilter binary file?
3) Created a symlink using  "ln -sf ~/path/to/filter ~/bin/filter".
4) refreshed current terminal session using "source ~/.bashrc".

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're using some kind of *nix system. So what you need to do is to put the binary in a directory that exists in your `PATH` environment variable. On my system it looks like this:

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
```

So either put the binary in one of those, or add an extra directory to `PATH`

Assuming a Linux system (might work on BSD or Mac too) you edit the file `~/.bashrc` and add the line `export PATH="<your/custom/path>:$PATH"`. Note that editing `.bashrc` this file will only do this for the current user.

If you want the particular executable available for all users, then instead of creating a bin directory in your home directory, add it in /usr. For example `mkdir /usr/mybin` and edit `/etc/profile` instead of `~/.bashrc`. My file has these lines:

```
if [ "`id -u`" -eq 0 ]; then
  PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
else
  PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games"
fi
export PATH
```

Add the line `PATH="/usr/mybin:$PATH"` so you get:

```
if [ "`id -u`" -eq 0 ]; then
  PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
else
  PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games"
fi
PATH="/usr/mybin:$PATH
export PATH
```

With this method you will make `/usr/mybin` appear in all users paths. Make sure that the directory and executable has correct permissions. Use the command `chmod 755 /usr/mybin` and `chmod 755 /usr/mybin/filter`. An alternative is to put the file in a directory that is already in the path, like `/usr/bin`. But you still need to make sure it has 755 permissions.

Comment: Thanks so much for clearing it up, Klutt. I set it up and it works yay!